# Error when filtering some data with like and jsonb in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I keep having a problem when filtering some data in postgresql.
For example, I want to filter by a json.
My jsons are saved in the following way

```
"[{\"Brand\":\"Leebo\"},{\"Housing Color\":\"Black\"},{\"Beam Type\":\"High Beam, Low Beam\"}]"
```

And let's say that I want to filter after

```
[{\"Brand\":\"Leebo\"}]
```

Shouldn't I write something like that in the query?

```
SELECT * FROM public.products
WHERE attributes is not NULL 
AND attributes::text LIKE '%{\"Brand\":\"Leebo\"}%';
```

I tried also

```
SELECT * FROM public.products WHERE attributes::jsonb @> '"[{\"Material\":\"Artificial Leather\"}]"'
```

Because I won't receive data
Do you know how I could proceed differently?

But it only works if the column has all the data (eg if I give the exact data that is in the column)

Also, how could I search with whereIn?

Comment: What is the data type of the column, and are you sure that you stored these syntactically incorrect backslashes?

Comment: Type of column is jsonb

Comment: Your first example is a **single**  JSON _string_, not an array. It would be an array if it was saved like this: `[{"Brand": "Leebo"}, {"Housing Color": "Black"}, ....]`

Comment: But can I do a search for only a few elements if it is a json string? like this %{\"Brand\":\"Leebo\"}%

Comment: I saved them as json and not json string, but I still can't

Comment: Well treating the JSON value as a huge string and searching with LIKE isn't the same as doing a proper JSON comparison: https://dbfiddle.uk/oIPr_vsg

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to search in all json columns with whereIn?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array in your JSONB because those characters (`[` and `]`) are array characters. If you are sure that you will always have only one array in your JSONB so you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM public.products
WHERE attributes is not NULL 
AND attributes[0]->>'Brand' = 'Leebo'
```

But if you can have several arrays inside JSONB then use `jsonb_array_elements` for extracting array elements, after then you can use JSONB operations like as `->>`